# Map domain to local ip

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain, mapping

I have the application running on the local server. I want to map the domain with the local server so that we can view the data online......Please it urgent?

my local IP address is

92.168.56.101

Answer (score 1):

First off we don't come with an SLA if it's really urgent hire someone to do the job.

The basic steps are

- Register your domain with a registrar

  - choose one that provides easy to use DNS configuration it'll be easier for you.
- In your registrar's DNS configuration utility

  - Create an A record for your host that points to your IP Address
  - ditto AAAA records (if required)
  - ditto CNAME records (if required)

If your 'server' is directly connected to the public internet then you should be good to go. If however you have a border device you may need to configure it to port forward the relevant ports to your server.

I'm sure you'll have lots of questions but first take a look at the relevant sections of the [TCP/IP guide](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/index.htm) in particular [Chapter 9](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPIPDomainNameSystemDNS.htm) read the documentation provided by your registrar on the tools they provide and the documentation provided for your border device (if required).